# Issue in getting a write access violation while assigning string index to char?

Tags: c++

For a school assignment, I am writing a program to implement the Vignere cipher. I have been provided the following header file:

**Keyprovider.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class KeyProvider
{
private:
    char * fKeyword;    // keyword
    size_t fSize;       // length of keyword
    size_t fIndex;      // index to current keyword character
    
public:
    
    // Initialize key provider.
    // aKeyword is a string of letters.
    KeyProvider( const std::string& aKeyword );

    // Destructor, release resources.
    ~KeyProvider();
    
    // Initialize (or reset) keyword
    void initialize( const std::string& aKeyword );
    
    // Dereference, returns current keyword character.
    char operator*() const;
    
    // Push new keyword character.
    // aKeyCharacter is a letter (isalpha() is true).
    // aKeyCharacter replaces current keyword character.
    // Key provider advances to next keyword character.
    KeyProvider& operator<<( char aKeyCharacter );
};
```

Below is the `.cpp` file code snippet that is causing errors:

**KeyProvider.cpp**

```
#include "KeyProvider.h"

using namespace std;

KeyProvider::KeyProvider(const std::string& aKeyword) {

    fIndex = 0;
    fSize = aKeyword.length();
    fKeyword[fIndex] = aKeyword[fIndex];
}
```

The line `fKeyword[fIndex] = aKeyword[fIndex]` gives a write Access Violation, however I am not sure why this is occurring as I confirmed with other people that this is, in fact, the correct way to initialize the `fKeyword` variable in the `KeyProvider` class.

What could potentially be causing this error to occur?

Comment: Why are you assigning to `fKeyword[fIndex]` instead of simply `fKeyword`?

Comment: Ask yourself: What `char` object does `fKeyword` point to?

Comment: @jarmod if i try to assign to fKeyword i get the error 'a value of type "char" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char*"'

Comment: Q: Where are you allocating memory for fKeyword??? `char * fKeyword` is just a pointer; it needs to point to a valid object!

Comment: While the header file doesn't explicitly say, I would assume that your constructor should copy the provided string `aKeyword` and store it in `fKeyword`, so you need to allocate memory to do that because, as it stands, `fKeyword` doesn't point to any usable memory.

Comment: The obvious question to me is, why is `fKeyword` not declared as a `std::string` when the the code is using `std::string` everywhere else?  OK, it wasn't your choice, you didn't write the header file, but I would return it to the shop I got it from and ask for a refund.  Your professor is obviously trying to teach you how to allocate memory dynamically, but that's no longer a useful skill.  People don't do it that way anymore, it's all taken care of by the containers (including, but not limited to, `std::string`) provided by the STL.  Sorry for the rant, but this kind of thing annoys me.

Answer (score 2):

> The line `fKeyword[fIndex] = aKeyword[fIndex]` gives a write Access Violation, however I am not sure why this is occurring

You are not allocating any memory for `fKeyword` to point at, so you can't index into it.  You need something more like this instead:

```cpp
KeyProvider::KeyProvider(const std::string& aKeyword) {
    fIndex = 0;
    fSize = aKeyword.length();
    fKeyword = new char[fSize];
    aKeyword.copy(fKeyword, fSize);
}
```

You need similar code in `KeyProvider::initialize()`, too.

A better option is to change `fKeyword` to be a `std::string` instead of a `char*` (if you are allowed to).  Then you won't need `new[]`, and you can get rid of your `fSize` member and your destructor.

> I confirmed with other people that this is, in fact, the correct way to initialize the `fKeyword` variable in the `KeyProvider` class.

Then either you were told wrong, or more likely you just misunderstood what they told you.